# Suddenly unable to push to git repository

Tags: git, version-control

Originally, I was able to push to my git repository, but after I merged a git branch and deleted the local branch, but didn't delete the remote branch, I am unable to push to the git repository. I am also unable to delete the remote branch now.

Things I've tried:

```
git checkout master
git pull --which works
git checkout feature_branch
git merge master
#already up to date wut?
```

```
git checkout feature_branch
git push
```

result:
`remote: Repository not found`

Does anyone know what's up with this?

edit:
results of 'git push -vv'

```
 branch1 _____ [origin/feature/branch1: ahead 3] Merge branch 'master' into branch1 commit_message1
  branch2 ____ [origin/feature/branch2: ahead 1] commit_message2
  master  ______ [origin/master] Merge pull request #xx from branch3
```

results of `git config --local -l`

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/repo
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.feature/name1.remote=origin
branch.feature/name1.merge=refs/heads/feature/branch1
branch.feature/name1.remote=origin
branch.feature/name2.merge=refs/heads/feature/name2
branch.name2.remote=origin
branch.name2.merge=refs/heads/name2
```

Comment: Try posting the output of `git branch -vv`. Feel free to remove confidential commit messages first but do leave the tracked remote branch names (the ones inside square brackets).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first "already up to date":

```
git checkout feature_branch
git merge master
#already up to date wut?
```

That happens if `master` is a direct ancestor of the `feature_branch`: there would nothing to merge, because `master` commits are already part of `feature_branch` commits.

For the second "already up to date":

```
git checkout feature_branch
git push
```

That happens if there are no new commits on feature_branch locally, and the existing ones were already pushed before.

To check that, do:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all --branches
```

If you see `feature_branch` and `origin/feature_branch` on the same commit... there is nothing more to push.

```
git pull --which works
```

If pull works, but push does not, that means an authentication issue which makes GitHub believe you don't have the right to push.

Check, for HTTPS URL, [your `git config credential.helper`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git): you might have the wrong username/password cached and will need to remove it.

Comment: the result of the push is not "up to date", it's "remote: repository not found"

Comment: And the strange thing is, I'm still able to pull my code from my repo, but I can't push.

Comment: @coderboi Can you edit the question with the result of `git config --local -l`? (executed from within your repository)

Comment: @coderboi I see that `feature/name2` has no remote. Can you try, after `git checkout feature/name2` a `git push -u origin feature/name2`

Comment: The result is still "repository not found"

Comment: @coderboi What does `git remote -v` return? It should include `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>`, not `https://github.com/<repo>`.

Comment: git remote -v returns `https://github.com/<repo>`, but even if I change to `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>`, I still get the same result

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. For some reason, I no longer have write permissions to the repository. I'll figure out why.

Comment: @coderboi Good point. I have edited the answer to reflect that.